# How to get a lightbox from a link with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

For my project I must click a button that says "More Information", and when this is clicked, a light box should appear with a table displaying more information.

Right now in my HTML I have a table:

```
< tr>

< td>Rules < /td>

< td>< input type="text" name="ruls" id="rules" value="" />

    < div>
    < a href="#" onClick="javascript:displayBox()">More Information< /a>
    < /div>

< /td>

< /tr>
```

Now I am unsure what to put in the href=" " .

Do I put the function I have which is displayBox, in the link?

Therefore, `< a href=" " onClick="javascript:displayBox()"> Rules < /a>`...
but again, I am unsure of what to put in the href .

Comment: follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Best practices are to not put any javascript in your html incase the user has Javascript disabled.

try this:

```
<tr>  
    <td>Rules </td>
    <td>< input type="text" name="ruls" id="rules" value="" />
      <div>
        <a href="#" id="displayBox">More Information</a>
      </div>   
   </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var myEl = document.getElementById('displayBox');

  myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
      displayBox();
  }, false);

</script>
```

Comment: Moving the JS out of an onclick attribute and into a script is good style, but doesn't stop the link having `href="#"`, which is useless if JS is disabled.